# SSL error: cannot connect with url (curl) in c

Tags: linux, curl, url, gcc, openssl

$ Sudo curl URL

curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to URL Link

I am getting this error...
anyone have exact solution of this?
I tried lot of ways to resolve it, but it didn't work.

I tried to resolve it provided solutions in stack overflow, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

please check the network connectivity by pinging from domain name and then trace domain name
if any things is okey change your nameserver
hope is help full

Comment: Network Connectivity is okay , this problem arises sometimes only